# Building a login module in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-login

I'm trying to build a login module in django that works independently from the page you are on.

I'm defining the login module in a base.html template that contains the header (the login module sits in the header) all other pages extend this base template.

My plan was to pass the error through the context dictionary, the problem is that I don't know how to make the function render() render the template from which the user attempted to login.

this is my view code:

```
def login(request):
    context_dict = {}
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('login_username')
        password = request.POST.get('login_password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if not user:
            context_dict['error'] = 'שם משתמש או סיסמא אין נכונים'
        elif not user.is_active:
            context_dict['error'] = 'חשבונך נחסם, אם הינך חושב שזאת טעות צור קשר עם מנהל בהקדם.'
        else:
            login(request,user)
            redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    render(request, ', context_dict)
```

Comment: If you want to get back to the previous page, do not render it. Redirect will do better for your application. Put a `next` parameter on the request and check it after login. If the parameter exist, then redirect to that url.

Comment: I've solved the case where login is succseful by simple using:
redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

the problem is that I want to render login errors if it is unsuccesful and to do that I need to render the template with a context dictionary to store the errors. 

I don't know which template to render because I don't know which template the user came from because you can login from any template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, the trick is using the Django messages framework.

here is the code and explanation for anyone who wants to implement something similar:

**simple url routing in urls.py file**

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, name='logout'),
```

**two views, one for login one for logout**

```
def login(request):
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST.get('login_username')
        password = request.POST.get('login_password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if not user:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'wrong username or password') 
        elif not user.is_active:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'your account is disabled') 
        else:
            django_login(request,user)
            return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))


def logout(request):
    django_logout(request)
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

**modified import to avoid a recursion error (in views.py)**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as django_login, logout as django_logout
```

**and finally displaying message in template**

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class='login_error'>
            {{ message }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```